# How can I manually find the coefficients, poles and zeros of Butterworth low pass filter in MATLAB instead of using the built-in functions?

Tags: matlab, filters, butterworth

Actually I need to filter a raw ECG signal using low pass Butterworth filter at 70 hertz. And j need to implement the Butterworth filter first for that. Please any help since I'm very new to this MATLAB. Thanks

Comment: Why can't you use the built in functions ?

Comment: Have you looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterworth_filter#Digital_implementation .  The actual  formula is simple but it's worth the practice to follow the links.

Comment: Since i need to implement this manually instead of using the built-in functions, i am asking for help. Thanks.